SQL table join changes case aggregate expression logic
Using the code below, when I use the case expression without joining tables together, I have no issue.
select t1.PNODE_ID, --t2.NODE_ID,
case
    when STRING_AGG(t1.AS_REGION_ID, ',') = 'AS_SP26,AS_SP15' then 'SP15'
    when STRING_AGG(t1.AS_REGION_ID, ',') = 'AS_SP15,AS_SP26' then 'SP15'
    when STRING_AGG(t1.AS_REGION_ID, ',') = 'AS_NP26,AS_NP15' then 'NP15'
    when STRING_AGG(t1.AS_REGION_ID, ',') = 'AS_NP15,AS_NP26' then 'NP15'
    when STRING_AGG(t1.AS_REGION_ID, ',') = 'AS_SP15,AS_NP26' then 'ZP26'
    when STRING_AGG(t1.AS_REGION_ID, ',') = 'AS_NP26,AS_SP15' then 'ZP26'
    else 'Unknown'
end as CLEANED_ZONE
from ATL_AS_REGION_MAP t1
--left join ATL_CBNODE t2 on t1.PNODE_ID = t2.NODE_ID
group by 
t1.PNODE_ID
--t2.NODE_ID


However, when I try to join the tables together, the "else" expression is called for any time there is a matching NODE_ID name. If there is no matching NODE_ID name, the case expression executes as expected.

I would like to understand why this is happening and how to join the tables together with the case expression appropriately.
The case expression is defined off the following column output:
select t1.PNODE_ID, STRING_AGG(t1.AS_REGION_ID, ',') as AGG_STRING, t2.NODE_ID,
case
    when STRING_AGG(t1.AS_REGION_ID, ',') = 'AS_SP26,AS_SP15' then 'SP15'
    when STRING_AGG(t1.AS_REGION_ID, ',') = 'AS_SP15,AS_SP26' then 'SP15'
    when STRING_AGG(t1.AS_REGION_ID, ',') = 'AS_NP26,AS_NP15' then 'NP15'
    when STRING_AGG(t1.AS_REGION_ID, ',') = 'AS_NP15,AS_NP26' then 'NP15'
    when STRING_AGG(t1.AS_REGION_ID, ',') = 'AS_SP15,AS_NP26' then 'ZP26'
    when STRING_AGG(t1.AS_REGION_ID, ',') = 'AS_NP26,AS_SP15' then 'ZP26'
    else 'Unknown'
end as CLEANED_ZONE
from ATL_AS_REGION_MAP t1
left join ATL_CBNODE t2 on t1.PNODE_ID = t2.NODE_ID
group by 
t1.PNODE_ID,
t2.NODE_ID



@topsail I have included AS_REGION_ID. As you can see, a single PNODE can have multiple AS_REGION_ID values.

Can you please query SELECT @@version; to confirm what brand and version of SQL database you are using? You have tagged your question 'mysql' but MySQL does not have a function STRING_AGG(). That function is implemented in Microsoft SQL Server.

@BillKarwin I have updated the tag to sql-server. thanks

I see. So I should have said you should include STRING_AGG(t1.AS_REGION_ID, ',') in your query results to confirm what the aggregated regions are (which you are using as the key criterion in your CASE)

@topsail I did include it? I added it as an additional screenshot to the end.

Please do not use images! Express your data as formatted text using table markdown.

Note that you can simplify your case statement with in. when STRING_AGG(t1.AS_REGION_ID, ',') in ('AS_SP26,AS_SP15', 'AS_SP15,AS_SP26') then 'SP15'

It really doesn’t look like you included the requested example. Equivalent debugging option: 'Unknown' -> 'Unknown (' || STRING_AGG(t1.AS_REGION_ID, ',') || ')'

@topsail Thanks for your comments. I understand why it is not working from the latest edit I made. I do not understand why agg_string values are duplicated now. If i do not perform a join, the node 0096WD_7_N001 AGG_STRING values are AS_NP26,AS_SP15 not AS_NP26,AS_SP15,AS_NP26,AS_SP15

You must have more rows that match now ... so you see "duplicates" so to speak.

You can resolve these zones in a CTE prior to your left join (the same way you did without the left join, where you found it was working correctly):
;with cte as (
    select 
        ar.PNODE_ID,
        case
            when STRING_AGG(ar.AS_REGION_ID, ',') in ('AS_SP26,AS_SP15','AS_SP15,AS_SP26') then 'SP15'
            when STRING_AGG(ar.AS_REGION_ID, ',') in ('AS_NP26,AS_NP15','AS_NP15,AS_NP26') then 'NP15'
            when STRING_AGG(ar.AS_REGION_ID, ',') in ('AS_SP15,AS_NP26','AS_NP26,AS_SP15') then 'ZP26'
            else 'Unknown'
        end as CLEANED_ZONE
    from ATL_AS_REGION_MAP ar
    group by ar.PNODE_ID
)
select distinct
    cte.PNODE_ID,
    acb.NODE_ID,
    cte.CLEANED_ZONE
from 
    cte
    left join ATL_CBNODE acb 
    on cte.PNODE_ID = acb.NODE_ID;
    
    


Thank you, this worked great! I added a distinct statement.

Once you join those tables together, you could end up multiplying out the rows, unless the join is on a unique row.
Looks like you should probably just use conditional COUNTs instead of doing this weird string aggregation.
SELECT
  rm.PNODE_ID,
  cbn.NODE_ID,
  CASE
    WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN rm.AS_REGION_ID = 'AS_SP15' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'SP15'
    WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN rm.AS_REGION_ID = 'AS_NP15' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'NP15'
    WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN rm.AS_REGION_ID = 'AS_NP26' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'ZP26'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
  END as CLEANED_ZONE
FROM ATL_AS_REGION_MAP rm
LEFT JOIN ATL_CBNODE cbn ON rm.PNODE_ID = cbn.NODE_ID
GROUP BY
  rm.PNODE_ID
  cbn.NODE_ID;


Part of the issue was that a single PNODE could take multiple AS types. I.e. AS_SP15, AS_SP26. The PNODE would have two rows for both types in the original data. I was unable to use the above code due to this reason.

Why not, why would this not work? All this does is check in order if there are any AS_SP15 regions in the group it returns SP15 and so on.
